# Following Code Return Null

Tags: java, android

The following code return null... can anybody tell me why ?

```
public Location getLocation(){
       LocationManager locationManager;
       String context = Context.LOCATION_SERVICE;
       locationManager = (LocationManager) mContext.getSystemService(context);

       String provider = LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER;
       Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
       return location;
   }
```

Comment: because `getLastKnownLocation` returns null

Comment: IF your device GPS is off, then there can be 1 possibilities..

Comment: first tell what is your need?

Comment: want to to get LatLong

Answer (score 2):

Because the GPS Provider needs some time to lock on a Satelite before its returns last known location.

If you need to get the best position by GPS you have to use the request update mechanism of the location manager and then handle the location update event to get the location over gps.

Best practice I use is the following worflow:

1. Check for GPS
2. If gps available and useable, request update.
3. Return last known position by network or low power profile, which always gives a location.
4. When location update event comes, update gui again with precise location from GPS.

Good starting point is here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html